# If i keep those script code in the html file no error occurs, But if i kept in another individual script file, yup error occurs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!-- HTML FILE-->

Gender      :   <label ng-repeat="option in gend">
   <input type="radio" ng-model="$parent.option" ng-value="option">{{option.I}}{{option.O}}</label></br></br> 


<!--Module-->

angular.module("appy", []);


<!-- Controller-->

appy.controller('Cont',function($scope){

    $scope.user='';
    $scope.pas='';
    $scope.selected='male';
    $scope.gend=['male','female'];
    $scope.addr='';
    $scope.emailid='';

    $scope.coun=[ I='India',O='Other'];
    $scope.ph='';
    $scope.pincode='';

    $scope.movedude = function() {
        window.location = "Redir.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to add details of what error occurs, and to show how you include the other script file - help us to help you by including everything we need to know.

Comment: make sure you are loading that script file in your index.html (Y)

Comment: Please show how you are including the your script file in `HTML` page. Also try changing `angular.module("appy", []);` to `var appy = angular.module("appy", []);`

Answer (score 0):

`appy` or your app name, exists only within Angular. Your browser does not know of it's existence. So you should either chain your controller and module definitions or assign your module to a variable and use that variable across the board. This is not correct:

```
angular.module("appy", []);  
appy.controller('Cont',function($scope){});
```

Instead try chaining:

```
angular.module("appy", [])  
.controller('Cont',function($scope){});
```

or using a JS variable:

```
var app = angular.module("appy", []);  
app.controller('Cont',function($scope){});
```

Comment: @Mohu If my answer helped, please mark as correct and upvote :)